# Default property when none matching - Python

Tags: python, properties, default

I have browsed the web and pydoc to find my answer without success.
My issue is the following:

I want to define a class with properties, as I would do habitually.

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, content):
        assert isinstance(content, dict), "The container can only contain a dictionary"
        self._content = content

    @property
    def name():
        try:
            return self._content["its_name"]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError
```

Now, to access the content's field "`its_name`", I can use `container.name`, with a slight modification between the field's name and the attribute's.

I would like to have a default behavior when no specific getter property is set.
I mean, if I call `container.description`, I want my class to try returning `self._content["description"]`, and throw an `AttributeError` if there is no such key.
While still calling the specific property for cases like `container.name`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `__getattr__` special method is for:

```
def __getattr__(self, attrname):
    # Only called if the other ways of accessing the attribute fail.
    try:
        return self._content[attrname]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError
```

Note that if for some reason you try to retrieve an unknown attribute when the `_content` attribute doesn't exist, the line

```
        return self._content[attrname]
```

will recursively invoke `__getattr__` in an attempt to get the `_content` attribute, and that call will call `__getattr__`, and so on until stack overflow.

Comment: You can guard against that by checking that `attrname != '_content'`, but with the constructor like this it can't really happen.

Comment: Another way to guard against it would be to use `super(Container, self).__getattribute__('_content')`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I knew there were such a default method, but I couldn't remember what it was. Thanks a lot, you save me a great amount of time :)

Comment: @user2357112, how would you use it ? How would you bind it to Container.__getattr__ ?

Comment: @carrieje: The `super` call would be used to fetch the `_content` attribute inside `__getattr__`. It wouldn't be bound directly to `Container.__getattr__`.